# Managing named windows with javascript

Tags: javascript

Is there any way to access opened windows (tabs) via javascript that have a name set by the window.name propriety but were not created by the window.open() method. The windows contain documents from the same domain, so no security related problem should rise. If no cross-browser solution exist I would also be interested in browser-dependent methods (if any). Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

browser security does not allow that I am afraid (and actually should never, since its a HUGE security hole - talk about XSS).

You can only access them if opened by window.open().

The only theoretical way to do that is to create ie. a xul app/extension (firefox) - this would then have full access to the browser objects (where the frames/windows are just dom-elements as well)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there sure is a way. You will have to write your own browser that leaves this security hole, and then figure out some way to get people to use it.